# Find the power series of $f(x) = 10x^2 \arctan(x^5)$ and the lowest term with a nonzero coefficient

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The function $f(x) = 10x^2 \arctan(x^5)$ is represented as a power series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty = c_n x^n $$

**Q: What is the lowest term $n$ with a nonzero coefficient?**

What I've tried so far:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2)^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$$
$$...$$ Integrate both sides, replace $x$ with $x^5$, then multiply by $10x^2$ to get 
$$f(x) = 10x^2 \arctan(x^5) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 10\frac{(-1)^n} {2n+1}x^{10n+7}$$

Now, I'm assuming $c_n = 10\frac{(-1)^n} {2n+1}$, and is the coefficent of $x^n$. Then when $n = 0$, $c_n = 10$, which is nonzero. However, this is incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\newcommand{\n}{\color{red}{n}}$The $n$ in the question $\sum\limits_{\n =0}^{\infty}c_\n x^\n$ is different to the $n$ in your final sum. I suggest using a different letter in your final sum (e.g. $k$) to avoid confusion. Anyway, if you just write out the first few terms of the series, it should be clearer. Recall that $\arctan t = t -t^3/3 + t^5/5 - \cdots$. So $\arctan\left(x^5\right) = x^5 - \cdots$. Try multiplying now by $10x^2$.

Comment: $c_0=10$ seems to be correct. Who is claiming otherwise?

Comment: @Rócherz When asked, "What is the lowest term with a nonzero coefficient? $n =$ *insert number here* " I entered 0 and was marked as incorrect. Perhaps I am interpreting the question itself incorrectly?

Comment: As I said, the $n$ in your final sum is different to the $n$ written in the question. The $n$ that the question is asking for is *the power of $x$*. The $n$ in your final sum is not the power of $x$; rather, $10n+7$ is the power of $x$. So it might be less confusing if you use $k$ instead of $n$ for your final sum. The question is just asking for what minimal power of $x$ we have a non-zero coefficient.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I see that you are leading me to the series $10x^7 - \frac{10x^{17}}{3} + \frac{10x^{27}}{5} ...$, but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. In this series the coefficient of x is 10, but how is that related to the power series I am trying to create?

Comment: The question isn't asking for the coefficient. It's basicslly asking you what is the smallest power of $x$ in the series (with a non-zero coefficient).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Ahh I see. Thank you! I should have heeded your warning as not differentiating between the $n$'s confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\arctan(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$$

$$\arctan(x^5) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{10k+5}$$

$$10x^2\arctan(x^5) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k10}{2k+1}x^{10k+7}$$

The lowest term with a non-zero coefficient is $10x^7$ which is obtained when we substitute $k=0$.